# How to design database for tracking orders with set max items

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, extjs, data-modeling

I've got the following scenario:

In an order tracking system where sales reps track their orders:
Each order can have a total of 4 product types(commissionable buckets) and each bucket can 1 or none products of that product type.

So at max an order can have 4 products(one of each of the possible types)

The information I need to track for each of the four product types is the same:  product-sold-id(fk), status,  product-given-id(fk)

What would be the advantages of adding 12 columns to the order table: 3 for each product type like product-type1-sold-id, product-type1-status, product-type1-given-id..... Etc?

This would be easiest but my issue with this is that most orders would only have 2 or 3 product types sold which would result in 3 null fields per product type not sold.  With 100 reps @ 10 orders per day this would result in a lot of null fields.

I am leaning toward have an order items table with an order-id(fk) to cut down on all the null fields.
The issue with this approach would be that for one, I would have to add a level of complexity to either my client code to handle nested data, or my server code would have to flatten the data when requested and also be able to parse and save the flat data when sent modified from the client.  Also with 100 reps@10 orders per day with 1-4 product  types per order this would result in 1000-4000 rows added to the order items table per day. Is there any way of overcoming this?

Any advice would be appreciated.  I am using extjs clientside, php serverside, with MySQL as my db.

Comment: Normally it is best to have two separate tables. With proper indexing you shouldn't have any issues with the number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a [standard order data model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471380237), and put your application logic where it belongs, i.e. in the application layer (or maybe db sprocs).

What if your order maximum of 4 changes?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep orders, products, and product types in their own tables. Then, you will use foreign keys to LEFT JOIN the tables together when returning results in PHP. This will allow you to scale the application with minimal effort. For example, adding up to five types to a product will require no changes to the database structure. Everything will be handled within the PHP code when limiting product types and products per order.

The foreign key is simply just a pointer to another table. For example, the table product_types should have a column named product_id for the primary key of the related product. The same works for products within an order. This is a very common way to represent one-to-many or many-to-many relationships.

For a code example, this is how you would return an order with the products.

```
SELECT * FROM products AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders AS o ON o.id=p.order_id
WHERE o.id=1234;
```